# CSS nested menu is not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

I have a basic nested menustruct:

http://jsfiddle.net/vqnUP/

```
#topmenu
{
    min-height: 54px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

#topmenu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

#topmenu ul li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px 2.5% 17px 2.5%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #6e6b6b;
    position: relative;
}

#topmenu ul li:last-child
{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#topmenu ul li:first-child
{
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

#topmenu ul li img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#topmenu a
{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 54px;
}

#topmenu ul li ul{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
}

#topmenu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

#topmenu ul li ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 2.5% 17px 2.5%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #6e6b6b;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#topmenu ul li ul li:last-child{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#topmenu ul li ul li:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

#topmenu ul li ul li img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
<div id="topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class=""><a href="home"><img src='/assets/upload/pagemenu/home.png' /></li>
        <li class=""><a href="tanar">Tanßr</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="diak">Dißk</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="szulo">SzŘl§</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="nyelviskola">Nyelviskola</a></li>
        <li class="">
        <a href="boltok">Boltok</a>
        <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="">aaaaaaaa</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="">aaaaaaaaa</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="kapcsolat">Kapcsolat</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="linkek">Linkek</a></li>
        <li class="kiemelt"><a href="webshop">Webshop</a></li>
    </ul>
<div style="clear: both;"></div></div>
```

its almost OK, but the submenu in "Boltok" (containing aaaaaaa) doesnt appear excatly under the "Boltok" menu, but aligned to left. I can't figure out the mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a top and left to your sub menu

```
#topmenu ul li ul{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;

    top: 62px; /* added */
    left: 0; /* added */
    width: 100%; /* this will cause the submenu to take the 100% width of the containing li - optional? */
};
```

So we only target the first ul li's you change this class like this. Also added a float: left and changed the display to block

```
#topmenu > ul > li
{
    display: block; float: left;
    padding: 15px 2.5% 17px 2.5%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #6e6b6b;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vqnUP/2/

Comment: almost 100% but it adds unnecessary padding :)

Comment: I don't really know what your styling requirements are, but this one seems near perfect with the styling in the fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/vqnUP/3/

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCg89/)

I'm only addressing the issue you mentioned.

I have just added

`width:100%;` to `#topmenu ul li ul` and

`text-align:center;` to `#topmenu ul li ul li`.

Hope that helps...

Comment: it does help, although not the 100% solution